# Gamecenter crash when I check if player is logged in

Tags: ios, game-center

I have a crash on this line with bad access.

```
if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == YES)
```

I saw this code on several tutorials and I think it should work. Do I need to enable something before calling it?

EDIT: The crash is upper, on this line - I just separated the calls

```
player = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
player = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
```

crashed because there was no autorelease memory pool in place before the call. Weird crash...

Answer (score 2):

The getter is called `isAuthenticated` not `authenticated`. Use the following:

```
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated == YES)
```

There are more details in Apple's [Game Center User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/isAuthenticated)